# asp.net C# evento onblur recarga pagina completa

Tags: c#, asp.net

Buen día, tengo una página .aspx donde, dentro de un asp:UpdatePanel, existe un asp:TextBox al que le asigné un evento onblur, de la siguiente forma:

.aspx:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btn1OnBlur" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="btn1OnBlur_Click"></asp:Button>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

.aspx.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //Asignar evento onblur
txt1.Attributes.Add("onblur",Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btn1,""));
}

protected void btn1OnBlur_Click(object sender,EventArgs e){
  if(txt1.Text.Equals("")){
    LlenarControles(); //...
  }
}
```

El evento funciona bien, pero el problema es que recarga la página completa, y no sólo el **UpdatePanel**. Si tengo otra función con otro control y se dispara el mismo evento, **recarga la página una vez más** y borra los cambios que había hecho el evento anterior...

Comment: Luis, creo que **o no te entiendo bien** o creaste un evento `OnClick` en un botón llamado "OnBlur" = no es lo mismo un evento "OnClick" que un evento "OnBlur".

Answer (score 1):

No se alcanza a ver si tienes el ScriptManager definido

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

Por otro lado puede ser la ausencia del trigger, te recomendaría realizar hoy en día esta clase de trabajos con el ajax convencional y no con los controles de Microsoft, pero en caso que sea necesario usarlo, esta [página](http://dunderio.com/como-usar-updatepanels-explicado-para-humanos/) explica claramente como deberias realizarlo.

Comment: La etiqueta de ScriptManager estaba incluida, pero no la escribí en la pregunta, ya que Visual Studio 2015 no te deja probar o compilar el proyecto si en alguna página se define un UpdatePanel con la ausencia de un ScriptManager.

Comment: podrias añadir el codigo completo para intentar replicar el error, nos serviria a todos los que estamos intentando ayudarte. saludos!!

Comment: obviamente me refiero a la parte del codigo asociado directamente al problema, ya que ahora con lo que tengo no podria hacer correr el proyecto. saludos!!

Answer (score 0):

*(Además de agregar el `ScriptManager` tal como menciona el usuario manu_rit en su respuesta)*, debes declarar en tu `UpdatePanel` el elemento `Triggers` y a su vez, el elemento `AsyncPostBackTrigger`.

Modificando tu código, quedaría así:

```
<%-- Recuerda colocar la etiqueta ScriptManager: -- %>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txt1" runat="server"></TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btn1OnBlur" runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="btn1OnBlur_Click"></asp:Button>
  </ContentTemplate>
  <Triggers>
    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btn1OnBlur" EventName="Click" />
  </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Revisa este enlace para que comprendas mas sobre el uso del `UpdatePanel`.

[Understanding ASP.NET AJAX UpdatePanel Triggers](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers)

Comment: La etiqueta de ScriptManager ya estaba incluida, olvide mencionarla en la pregunta.Probé con asignar un Trigger y sigo sin tener buen resultado, la página se recarga completa.

Answer (score 0):

El problema que puedes tener es debido a que no esta encontrando la referencia al control. Tal vez con esta pequeña modificación sea la respuesta.

```
    txt1.Attributes.Add("onblur",Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(btn1OnBlur,""));
```

Espero y funcione. Saludos.

Comment: me equivoque al escribir la pregunta, lo tengo tal cual me escribes.